# whats (s.charAt(low) != s.charAt(high)) {" and " int high = s.length() - 1;

Tags: java, string, loops

So I was learning to code using a textbook and suddenly it gave an example using loops and it used a lot of concepts and code that I have previously never covered. Please can someone explain to me what `if (s.charAt(low) != s.charAt(high))` and  `int high = s.length() - 1;` are. Also, why is `low = 0`? I haven't learnt thıs yet. This is a code for finding palindromes. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter a string
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        // The index of the first character in the string
        int low = 0;

        // The index of the last character in the string
        int high = s.length() - 1;

        boolean isPalindrome = true;
        while (low < high) {
            if (s.charAt(low) != s.charAt(high)) {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
            low++;
            high--;
        }

        if (isPalindrome)
            System.out.println(s + " is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(s + " is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume, you enter the text, `Hello`.

Length of the text, `Hello` is `5`

`int high = s.length() - 1` means you are storing `4` (i.e. 5 - 1) to the variable, `high`. The index of the first character in a `String` is `0`. Therefore, the index of `H` in `Hello` is `0`, the index of `e` is `1` and so on. Thus the index of the last character, `o` is `4` which is equal to `"Hello".length() - 1`.

In the first iteration of the `while` loop, the condition, `if (s.charAt(low) != s.charAt(high))`, compares the first character (i.e. `H`) with the last character (i.e. `o`) of the text, `Hello`; because the value of `low` is `0` and that of `high` is `4`. This also answers your question,

> why is low = 0?

Had the character at index `0` been equal to the character at index `4`, the value of `low` would have incremented to `1` and the value of `high` would have been decremented to `3` so that in the next iteration of the `while` loop, the character at index `1` (i.e. the 2nd character) could be compared with that at index `3` (i.e. the second last character). However, in this case (i.e. when the input is `Hello`), `s.charAt(low) != s.charAt(high)` becomes `true` in the first iteration itself, causing the `while` loop `break` (i.e. stop executing the next iterations).

I recommend you understand the basics of Java from a good tutorial e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Wish you all the best!